# InfluxDB Grafana templates: Can't select all fields in "Add Query"

Tags: templates, influxdb, grafana, graphite

I believe I've done everything right when creating my graphite DB. Grafana can see the data but won't let me select all the fields when I try to "Add Query".

Output from my server shows that the DB is working:

```
show measurements
name: measurements

name
PORT

select * from "PORT"
name: PORT
time                CardNo Counter         Nodename    PortNo value
----                ------ -------         --------    ------ -----
1511214407000000000 18     bcast_inpackets ALPRGAGQPN2 1      500
```

However, when I try to "Add Query" in Grafana, I can see PORT in "FROM" (which is what I want), but in the "WHERE" section, when I try to narrow my selection using CardNo, Counter, etc., it appears to behave randomly. If I select CardNo first, it will let me select 18 (see picture below), but then clicking "+" to add another criteria doesn't display the option for say "PortNo" (all I get is an empty dialog box). I can enter the field value manually (eg PortNo) but other users will be plotting graphs and won't necessarily know the underlying schema. Also, if I select Nodename first, then I can select CardNo (weird). I'd like it so the end user can specify ALL the fields (in this case CardNo, Counter, Nodename and PortNo).

[image]

My graphite template is this:

```
"[[graphite]]
# Determines whether the graphite endpoint is enabled.
  enabled = true
  database = "graphite"
# retention-policy = ""
  bind-address = ":2003"
  protocol = "tcp"
# consistency-level = "one"
  templates = [ "ASR.PORT.* .measurement.Nodename.CardNo.PortNo.Counter"
  ]
```

and the data I feed to InfluxDB to test my setup is:

```
echo "ASR.PORT.ALPRGAGQPN2.18.1.bcast_inpackets 500 `date +%s`" | nc localhost 2003
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, template is better written as:

`"ASR.PORT.* .measurement.Nodename.CardNo.PortNo.field"`

Which makes `bcast_inpackets` and any other value after `PortNo` into a field containing data. This reduces cardinality of series, which improves performance and scalability, by combining all counters into multiple fields on the same series as opposed to separate series with unique tags with their own `value` fields.

Grafana's influx query builder will filter tag values for the value of the already selected tags. In other words, if you select `PortNo=1` and try to select another tag, only tag keys *where PortNo=1* will be shown.

If you look at queries Grafana runs in browser, you will see something like `show tag keys from PORT where PortNo='1'` if `PortNo=1` is already selected and different queries for other tags.

This is why you may not see other tags and why which tags you see depends on the tags already selected. This is by design so if you want something different you will need to adjust the schema by, for example, making `PortNo` and `CardNo` into fields instead of tags.

You might also be interested in [InfluxGraph](https://github.com/InfluxGraph/influxgraph) which can query InfluxDB via Graphite API and also supports same template configuration as InfluxDB.

Comment: I'm making some progress but not there quite yet. What I see is the resulting query when clicking on the "+" doesn't work (ie SHOW TAG KEYS FROM "PORT" WHERE "CardNo" = 1). When the '1' is in quotes then I see all the other fields. So the question now is how to make either Grafana enclose all values in quotes when doing the SELECT, or make submissions of new data from influxdb do it.

Comment: Can probably report that as a Grafana issue. A template where port and card no are fields sounds like it will work for you though, eg `.measurement.Nodename.field*`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it won't work for me because it pushes the selection down to the SELECT statement and I'll up with hundreds of choices which makes it unwieldy (eg I could have 20 cards with 20 ports each --> 400 choices). I reported my problem to Grafana but haven't heard anything yet. I'm leaning towards using the native influxdb syntax now instead of graphite if I can typecast those values. I figured out a workaround that isn't super pretty but it works by prefixing the CardNo (or any numerical field for that matter) with a ":". It "tricks" Grafana to treat it as a string.

Comment: Yes, selecting from multiple tags is a severe limitation of the Influx query language. This is one of the areas where the Graphite API is better suited at. Luckily, both can be used depending on the use case and needs of the user with [InfluxGraph](https://github.com/InfluxGraph/influxgraph)